# How many interrupts does my cpu have per second?

Tags: linux, cpu, interrupt

I have a 2.6 GHz Intel Core i7 running Linux. I am wondering how many interrupts on average my CPU gets per second.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: It depends on what it's doing.

Comment: "It depends" - best answer to any question, ever ^^

Comment: The question is a bit ambiguous. "It depends" is the most accurate answer you're going to get.

Comment: OMG the answer is literally in /proc/interrupts. "It depends". Sheesh. If only there was a way to downvote a comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using Linux you can

```
cat /proc/interrupts
```

And read the info with this page:

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/01/linux-interrupts/

cat the file every second to see how the counters have changed and then calculate an average.